# Why is JSON.parse sometimes returning errors when used with a string array?

Tags: javascript, json

In the function below, I'm using `JSON.parse()` on some string arrays stored in `window.sessionStorage` so I can then use methods like `.map()`.

```
window.sessionStorage = {
     myArray1: "["805746|search|4","980093062|search|0","980113648|search|1"]"
}

function mySessionStorage(strArr) {
    if (window.sessionStorage[strArr] &&
    typeof window.sessionStorage[strArr] === 'string' &&
    window.sessionStorage[strArr] !== '') {

      var myData = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage[strArr]);

      if (myData && typeof myData === 'object') {
        // ....
      }
    }
}
```

...which is then called like so:
`mySessionStorage('myArray1')`

But I'm seeing several errors logged in an analytics report and can't figure out why:

- `unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data in...`
- `unexpected token in json at position 6...`

At first I thought the culprit was a trailing comma, or perhaps an issue with quotes. But since this doesn't appear to be happening 100% of the time, I've been unable to replicate the issue myself.

What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to be using regular double quotes in a string surrounded by regular double quotes. This means that the javascript parser won't understand what you're trying to do. You should usually surround it with single quotes if you contain something with double quotes or you should use `\"` instead of `"` _inside_ of your string. Do you actually define `window.sessionStorage` as simply as this, or do you define it somewhere else in a more advanced way?

Comment: What would be a more advanced way to define window.sessionStorage? I'm not populating the window.sessionStorage property myself, just working with the data that's stored there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: in the declaration of `myArray1` you used double quotes inside double quotes. So use apostrophes  instead:

```
myArray1: '["805746|search|4","980093062|search|0","980113648|search|1"]'
```

Or escape quotes:

```
myArray1: "[\"805746|search|4\",\"980093062|search|0\",\"980113648|search|1\"]"
```